# Problem 2.7 Introduction to mechanics by Kleppner and Kolenkow

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

> A pole of negligible mass leans against a wall, at angle θ with the
> horizontal. Gravity is directed downwards.
> [image: 1]
>
> (a) Find the constraint relating the vertical acceleration of one end
> to the horizontal acceleration of the other.
> (b) Now suppose that each
> end carries a pivoted mass M. Find the initial vertical and horizontal
> components of acceleration as the pole just begins to slide on the
> frictionless wall and floor. Assume that at the beginning of the
> motion the forces exerted by the rod are along the line of the rod.
> (As the motion progresses, the system rotates and the rod exerts
> sidewise forces.)

I'm asking about part b. Consider the upper part. M is acted by gravity($\vec{P}$), and the force exerted by the pole($\vec{F_p}$) which is a normal force since M is sliding agianst the surface of the pole. It has two components which are $\vec{F_1}$ and $\vec{F_2}$. $\vec{F_2}$ is eliminated by the normal force of the vertical surface. So, we're left with $\vec{F_1}$ and therefore M will fall if $P$ is large enough. But by Newton's third law: The pole is also acted by a force $\vec{F'_p} = -\vec{F_p}$.

1. Is my analysis correct?
2. Does this force helps move the lower part or just eliminated by "some force" inside the pole itself like the ground eliminates the weight of an object which is exerted onto its surface?
3. Why is there the condition of "massless pole"?

Edit: Maybe the $\vec{F'_p}$ acts upon the system of a massless pole and a mass M, so it's just the same as $\vec{F'_p}$ acting upon M?

Answer (score 1):

The top mass is acted on by just three forces.  It's weight, the normal force from the wall and a force from the pole along the line of the pole.